# MD5 3DES encryption Swift

Tags: swift, encryption, md5, 3des, commoncrypto

I have an app that must send login credentials that have been encrypted first by MD5 and then by 3DES.

I have managed to use CryptoSwift to encrypt the string by MD5.
However I cannot find anything to encrypt by 3DES on Swift.

I have tried CommonCrypto. As far as I can tell this is in C but could be imported into Objective C with a bridging header.

I have found a few articles and tutorials that tell me how to import CommonCrypto into Swift, either by a bridging header(with the warning it will not work with frameworks) or by Model.map. However neither are working. Im not sure if this is a limitation in the latest versions of iOS or Xcode.

Could someone please advise an alternative?

Thanks

EDITED

Hi, please see the below steps I have taken

1. Ok so I created a new project called newEncrypt.
2. I chose not to use the header option as the instructions say this is limited to non Framework apps/
3. I created a folder inside newEncrypt called CommonCrypto, with a module.map file inside. the contents of which are: module CommonCrypto [system] {
   header "/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h"
   export *
   }
4. added ${SRCROOT}/CommonCrypto to swift compiler-search paths-import paths. Debug and release.
5. This is where the instructions sort of stop. I assume I need to import CommonCrypto into my class. This error with “could not build objective C module ‘CommonCrypto’.
   Im also assuming I should have the CommonCrypto library files (from the CommonCryto ‘include’ folder) in "/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h" or “/newEncrypt/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h"?
   I have tried this, but I just get the same errors.
6. I have then tried to ad a header file with #import   and added -lfoo to other linker flags debug and release (although this may not be the correct one) ust in case this could still be required. But I still get the same could not build objective c error.
   Im sure I am doing something wrong thats obvious

Comment: It is certainly possible to import CommonCrypto into Swift, though it is tedious. As you note, you've found several sites explaining the process. Without knowing what you have tried and what problems you've had, it's impossible to know what the alternative would be. "neither are working" does not tell us what your problem is.

Comment: MD5 is a hash not an encryption, and can easily be reversed using lookup tables (http://md5.gromweb.com/)

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly. I followed http://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/02/23/c-libraries-swift/ for one. I have tried to add a Model.map file withmodule CommonCrypto [system] {
    header "/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h"
    export *
} as the content in a CommonCrypto folder in the project. I have added the CommonCrypto library to the same location and also to an include folder in my user folder. I have also added the location to the swift complier import path

Comment: @ThundercatChris Your linked article looks fine. Yes, that should work. You should update your question to explain exactly what you've done and exactly what problem you're encountering (what error? what symptom? do you get a warning? does your computer catch on fire?) You should start with an empty project and practice getting CommonCrypto to link before trying it in a live project.

Comment: @RobNapier I have edited my original question to include the steps I have taken on a fresh project

Comment: Hi, Im still no further with this. Can anybody help please?

Comment: **WARNING**: Beware that using MD5 and 3DES may have been fine in the eighties, but that MD5 is considered broken and 3DES is only considered secure in specific circumstances. Please only use this Q/A for compatibility with ancient systems.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So it turns out I was completely overcomplicating this.

There is a really useful article already
http://www.stackoverflow.dluat.com/questions/31004609/how-to-convert-common-crypto-code-from-objective-c-to-swift

I didn't need to import any external libraries or SDKs, all I needed was a bridging header and to `#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myEncrypt("my string to encrypt") 
}

func myEncrypt(encryptData:String) -> NSData?{

        var myKeyData : NSData = ("myEncryptionKey" as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        var myRawData : NSData = encryptData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        var iv : [UInt8] = [56, 101, 63, 23, 96, 182, 209, 205]  // I didn't use
        var buffer_size : size_t = myRawData.length + kCCBlockSize3DES
        var buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<NSData>.alloc(buffer_size)
        var num_bytes_encrypted : size_t = 0

        let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
        let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithm3DES)
        let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)
        let keyLength        = size_t(kCCKeySize3DES)

        var Crypto_status: CCCryptorStatus = CCCrypt(operation, algoritm, options, myKeyData.bytes, keyLength, nil, myRawData.bytes, myRawData.length, buffer, buffer_size, &num_bytes_encrypted)

        if UInt32(Crypto_status) == UInt32(kCCSuccess){

            var myResult: NSData = NSData(bytes: buffer, length: num_bytes_encrypted)

            free(buffer)
            println("my result \(myResult)") //This just prints the data

            let keyData: NSData = myResult
            let hexString = keyData.toHexString()
            println("hex result \(hexString)") // I needed a hex string output


            myDecrypt(myResult) // sent straight to the decryption function to test the data output is the same
            return myResult
        }else{
            free(buffer)
            return nil
        }   
    }


func myDecrypt(decryptData : NSData) -> NSData?{

    var mydata_len : Int = decryptData.length
    var keyData : NSData = ("myEncryptionKey" as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

    var buffer_size : size_t = mydata_len+kCCBlockSizeAES128
    var buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<NSData>.alloc(buffer_size)
    var num_bytes_encrypted : size_t = 0

    var iv : [UInt8] = [56, 101, 63, 23, 96, 182, 209, 205]  // I didn't use

    let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCDecrypt)
    let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithm3DES)
    let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)
    let keyLength        = size_t(kCCKeySize3DES)

    var decrypt_status : CCCryptorStatus = CCCrypt(operation, algoritm, options, keyData.bytes, keyLength, nil, decryptData.bytes, mydata_len, buffer, buffer_size, &num_bytes_encrypted)

    if UInt32(decrypt_status) == UInt32(kCCSuccess){

        var myResult : NSData = NSData(bytes: buffer, length: num_bytes_encrypted)
        free(buffer)
        println("decrypt \(myResult)")

        var stringResult = NSString(data: myResult, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("my decrypt string \(stringResult!)")
        return myResult
    }else{
        free(buffer)
        return nil

    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I did the same as above. But i can't decrypt the text back from encrypted data. Can you update the answer with decrypting the text ?

Comment: @BalajiRamakrishnan I'm getting nil 50% of time.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the solution by @ThundercatChris and @DarkDust, I had to make a change to their solution as I was working with hex strings. There was a need to enforce the triple DES key length as the encryption/decryption was not working correctly without it.

```
import Foundation

extension Data {
    private func tripleDesKey() -> Data? {
        if self.count == 24 {
            return self
        }
        
        if self.count == 16 {
            var key = Data(capacity: 24)
            key.append(self.subdata(in: 0..<16))
            key.append(self.subdata(in: 0..<8))
            return key
        }
        
        return nil
    }
    
    private func tripleDesOp(key: Data, operation: CCOperation, options: CCOptions) -> Data? {
        guard let tempKey = key.tripleDesKey() else {
            return nil
        }
        let keyData = NSData(data: tempKey)
        let valueData = NSData(data: self)
        
        let bufferSize = valueData.length +  (UInt32(kCCEncrypt) == operation ? kCCBlockSize3DES : kCCBlockSizeAES128)
        let buffer =  UnsafeMutablePointer<NSData>.allocate(capacity: bufferSize)
        var bytes_encrypted: size_t = 0
        
        let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithm3DES)
        let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySize3DES)

        let ccStatus: CCCryptorStatus = CCCrypt(operation, algoritm, options, keyData.bytes, keyLength, nil, valueData.bytes, valueData.length, buffer, bufferSize, &bytes_encrypted)
        
        guard ccStatus == CCCryptorStatus(kCCSuccess) else {
            free(buffer)
            return nil
        }
        
        let dataOut = Data(bytes: buffer, count: bytes_encrypted)
        free(buffer)
        return dataOut
    }
    
    func tripleDesEncrypt(with key: Data) -> Data? {
        return tripleDesOp(key: key,operation: UInt32(kCCEncrypt), options: UInt32(kCCOptionECBMode))
    }
    
    func tripleDesDecrypt(with key: Data) -> Data?{
        return tripleDesOp(key: key, operation: UInt32(kCCDecrypt), options: UInt32(kCCOptionECBMode))
    }

}
```