# How to encrypt using 3DES in Swift

Tags: swift, 3des

I am struggling to find something to encrypt 3DES in swift. I have tried CommonCrypto, but I cannot get it working (I raised a separate issue on this). I also have CryotoSwift working for MD5, but it either doesn't do 3DES, or its not got the required code in place in the Objective C library.

Could someone please recommend something or is there an example of some swift code out there to do this? (Im not very good with Objective C)

Comment: Any solution found ?

Comment: No @Ali. Nothing yet

Comment: I have answered this under my other post. I hope this helps someone my use of the code
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433162/md5-3des-encryption-swift/31964639#31964639