# Is there a cipher method as in java, in swift?

Tags: java, swift, encryption

I'm trying to do a decrypt, but I don't really know how common crypto works on Swift. I have this code in java, and I have to convert to Swift, but I haven't been successful

I'm using swift 4.2 and Java 8

This function works in java

```
private static final String CIPHER_NAME = "DESede";
private static final String ALGORITHM = "MD5";
private static final String SECRET_KEY = "p3tr1c0r";
public static String decrypt(String encryptedText) {
 String base64EncryptedString;
 try{
    byte[] message = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest(SECRET_KEY.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));
    byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, CIPHER_NAME);

    Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_NAME);
    decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

    byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(message);

    base64EncryptedString = new String(plainText, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
}catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException ex){
    log.warn("Exception while trying to decrypt,  using encryptedText ");
    base64EncryptedString = encryptedText;
 }
return encryptedText;
}
```

For the moment I have this code for md5 digest, I know how I can convert to base 64 and vice versa, my problem is when I want to convert bytes, in java if I see the log, the bytes are negative, but in swift are unsigned bytes, is it the same? and my other problem is the `cipherDesede`, there is something similar on swift?

```
let str = "61880868013"
let buf: [UInt8] = Array(str.utf8)

func MD5(string: String) -> Data {
  let messageData = string.data(using:.utf8)!
  var digestData = Data(count: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH))

_ = digestData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {digestBytes in
    messageData.withUnsafeBytes {messageBytes in
        CC_MD5(messageBytes, CC_LONG(messageData.count), digestBytes)
    }
  }
return digestData
}
```

in java the input is uoqrHNWzb4XMQZoTQSGsHQ==

the output is 61880868013

Comment: Are you just trying to encrypt something, or does it specifically need to use DESede and MD5? [DESede has a really small key space because it's vulnerable to a meet-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Security), and MD5 is completely and utterly broken. Neither of these should be used anymore.

Comment: Try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433162/md5-3des-encryption-swift

Comment: Your code is using ECB, an insecure, unauthenticated cipher mode. You need to upgrade your protocol / encryption *pronto*.

Comment: If you remove `.name()` from `StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()` then you've got one exception less to worry about; that's why `StandardCharsets` was defined *in the first place*.

Comment: thanks to everyone, i know that md5 isn't the better, but i have to use it.

Answer (score 1):

> in Java if I see the log, the bytes are negative, but in swift are unsigned bytes, is it the same?

Yes, they are the same. The bits are simply interpreted differently, but for cryptography - or character encoding / decoding - only the bit values themselves matter.

> And my other problem is the cipher DES-EDE, there is something similar on Swift?

Swift doesn't seem to do too much crypto itself, but you can simply look for any implementation that does: triple DES / TDES / TDEA / 3DES or indeed DES-EDE (those are all the same) in ECB mode with PKCS#5 or PKCS#7 padding (also the same for triple DES).

One link shows [this example which uses CCCrypt underneath](https://github.com/phynet/Swift-CypherTripleDesEncrypt/blob/master/CypherSwift.swift), where it seems to be called 3DES, ECB and PKCS#7 padding, apparently.

Comment: thanks Maarten, i found a workaround, its working thanks